# Pronunciation of "bifurcate" as an adjective

Tags: pronunciation

It appears that the word "bifurcate" has a single spelling, but two possible pronunciations.

As a verb, according to both [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bifurcate#Pronunciation) and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bifurcate), the pronunciation of the verb is:

> /ˈbaɪfɚkeɪt/

Wiktionary additionally lists the following pronunciation for the adjective:

> /baɪˈfɝkət/

And dictionary.com says:

> /... adj. also ˈbaɪ fər kɪt, baɪˈfɜr-/

Forvo.com  has the [adjective](http://www.forvo.com/word/bifurcate_%28adjective%29/) sounding the same as the [verb](http://www.forvo.com/word/bifurcate/#en).

What is the proper pronunciation of "bifurcate" as an adjective? Is it *always* different as Wiktionary indicates? Can it be sometimes different (I think that's what dictionary.com is saying)?  Is it usually the same (as Forvo might be suggesting)?

Comment: But *bifurcate* is a verb. It would have to be *bifurcated*, wouldn't it?

Comment: OED gives the schwa form **/baɪˈfɜːkət/** for the *adjectival* usage, but I imagine most people would use ***bifurcated*** anyway, so the issue wouldn't arise. And I'm sure plenty of people who *do* use the adjectival form would just pronounce it the same as the verb anyway.

Comment: Surely 'bifurcate' as an adjective follows an established pattern  -  e.g. 'cruciate' as in 'cruciate ligament'.

Comment: English is not a defined language. Dictionaries can and do differ on things like pronunciation, and what you are seeing reflects this. There is no way to say that one dictionary is right and the others wrong.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I'm not asking for a definition, per se, I'm asking for an explanation of the situation.

Comment: @WS2 and Fumble: _Bifurcate_ does not mean quite the same as _bifurcated_. A _bifurcate tree_ is a tree whose trunk naturally consists of two main stems; a _bifurcated tree_ (if that were a thing) would be a tree whose stem had been cut or split up into two stems. Personally, I would pronounce the adjective differently from the verb, with a schwa in the final syllable. I waver between stressing the first or the second syllable, though.

Comment: The pronuncation of *bifurcate* with the stress on the second syllable sounds ridiculous to me, but I suspect that in a scientific field which uses the word *bifurcate* as a technical term, like botany, that's the way it's pronounced. If you're not in such a field, I recommend not using *bifurcate* at all.

Comment: @PeterShor Really, what my brain wants to do is only stress the first syllable, i.e., [ˈbaɪfɚkət]; but that would require destressing and shortening two syllables in a row, which seems to be disallowed. I kind of get to the start of the second syllable in the word and then realise that the unstressed [-fɚkət] goes against some kind of phonological rule and just sounds plain impossible, and then I end up giving secondary stress to the second syllable after all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a common thing in English to pronounce *adjectives* and even *nouns* ending in *ate* with a schwa, in contrast to *verbs* ending with the same letters:

I think most people would pronounce *intricate*, *accurate* and *prelate* with a schwa, but not *indicate* or *relate*.

*Bifurcate* simply follows the same pattern, getting pronounced as a verb or as an adjective depending on usage.

A similar things happens with *predicate*, which also has the same distinction in pronunciation according to [MerriamWebster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predicate).

(I just realized there are counterexamples, like *irate*... but no pattern is 100% foolproof.)

Comment: Well, the pattern holds if you restrict it to unstressed vowels! :)

Answer (score 1):

M-W Unabridged renders the adjective form of *[bifurcate](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/bifurcate)* as rhyming with "my fur kit."

It lists the pronunciation of the verb form as an acceptable *secondary* pronunciation for the adjective form, so apparently the adjective form isn't *always* pronounced differently.

I would suspect, however, that the sorts of people would use the adjective form of *bifurcate* (such as a *[bifurcate tongue](https://books.google.com/books?id=kwxl5jjQ-dUC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=intext:bifurcate%20intext:tongue&source=bl&ots=wC5YuCrZh2&sig=yJOqLXupSp5IQjnykSwam4BfrEU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HLfsVOW1Ls3voATen4GADw&ved=0CF4Q6AEwDg#v=onepage&q=intext%3Abifurcate%20intext%3Atongue&f=false)* -- as opposed to a *bifurcated tongue*, a truly bizarre body modification that some people undergo) would rhyme it with "my fur kit."

Comment: Good example of an actually occurring ‘minimal pair’ between _bifurcate_ and _bifurcated_ with a proper, perceivable difference!

Answer (score 1):

Nouns and adjectives in English have more of a tendency than verbs to shift stress to the left and to lose stress on non-primary stressed syllables on the right.  It's basically irregular where it has happened and consequently no rule is going to work for all examples. 1com2bine (farm implement) vs com1bine, 1record vs re1cord (hyphenation is after "c" for the noun but before it for the verb), 1delegate vs 1dele2gate, and so on.

Comment: For speakers who say /ˈbaɪfɚkeɪt/ (verb) and /baɪˈfɝkət/ (adjective), the stress is actually further to the left in the verb than in the adjective.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a distinction for some speakers between a verb pronounced /ˈbaɪfɚkeɪt/ (with primary stress on the first syllable) and an adjective pronounced /baɪˈfɝkət/ (with primary stress on the second syllable) appears to exist because for over two centuries, there have been two patterns for stressing polysyllabic words ending in *-ate,* and one of these patterns ended up becoming more common for verbs than for other parts of speech.

The Oxford English Dictionary entry for *contemplate* summarizes the situation as follows:

> In a few rare cases (Shakespeare, *Hudibras*) stressed *ˈcontemplate* in 16–17th cent.; also by Kenrick 1773, Webster 1828, among writers on pronunciation. Byron, Shelley, and Tennyson have both modes, but the orthoepists generally have *conˈtemplate* down to third quarter of 19th cent.; since that time *ˈcontemplate* has more and more prevailed, and *conˈtemplate* begins to have a flavour of age. This is the common tendency with all verbs in *-ate.* Of these, the antepenult stress is historical in all words in which the penult represents a short Latin syllable, as *acˈcelerate, ˈanimate, ˈfascinate, ˈmachinate, ˈmilitate,* or one prosodically short or long, as in *ˈcelebrate, ˈconsecrate, ˈemigrate;* regularly also when the penult has a vowel long in Latin, as *ˈalienate, ˈaspirate, conˈcatenate, ˈdenudate, eˈlaborate, ˈindurate, ˈpersonate, ˈruinate* (Latin *aliēno, aspīro,* etc.). But where the penult has two or three consonants giving positional length, the stress has historically been on the penult, and its shift to the antepenult is recent or still in progress, as in *acervate, adumbrate, alternate, compensate, concentrate, condensate, confiscate, conquassate, constellate, demonstrate, decussate, desiccate, enervate, exacerbate, exculpate, illustrate, inculcate, objurgate,* etc., all familiar with penult stress to middle-aged men. The influence of the noun of action in *-ation* is a factor in the change; thus the analogy of *ˌconseˈcration, ˈconsecrate,* etc., suggests *ˌdemonˈstration, ˈdemonstrate.* But there being no *remonstration* in use, *reˈmonstrate,* supported by *reˈmonstrance,* keeps the earlier stress.

So it used to be possible to pronounce not only polysyllabic adjectives ending in *-ate,* but also polysyllabic verbs ending in *-ate* with stress on the penult syllable, if the penult syllable was "closed" by a coda consonant in Latin.

However, stressing heavy penult syllables in polysyllabic *-ate* words became less common over the years, especially for verbs. I would guess that antepenult stress in words with heavy penult syllables has come to be more strongly established in verbs because, as others have pointed out, in verbs the ending *-ate* is pronounced with an unreduced vowel /eɪ/, which can be interpreted as a type of stress (according to some theories of stress), and English speakers have a tendency to prefer to stress alternating rather than adjacent syllables.

### Consummate

Another similar example that I know of is the verb *consummate* vs. the adjective *consummate*; the OED entry for the verb says

> N.E.D. (1893) records also the pronunciation (k*ǫ̆*ns*ɒ*·me<sup>i</sup>t) /kənˈsʌmeɪt/, with stress on the penultimate syllable. This pronunciation is listed in dictionaries until the late 19th cent.; sporadic evidence of the shift of stress from the penultimate to the antepenultimate (i.e. the first) syllable is found from the late 18th cent. onwards, but dictionaries and especially usage guides were slow to recognize it. From the 20th cent. onwards dictionaries record only first-syllable stress.
>
> [...] In the adjective consummate adj., both penultimate and antepenultimate stress are still found. N.E.D. (1893) recorded both stress positions in the adjective, noting that penultimate stress was ‘still usual’ at the time, but antepenultimate stress was also frequent.

### Bifurcate

As a matter of fact, some sources indicate that it is possible to stress the second syllable of *bifurcate* even as a verb: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bifurcate) says "verb  bi·fur·cate  \ ˈbī-(ˌ)fər-ˌkāt , bī-ˈfər- \" and the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bifurcate) says " (bī**´**fər-kāt´, bī-fûr**´**-)".