# Is there a parallel to defenestration -- for buses?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

We often see **defenestrate** used in a somewhat jocular, mock-intellectual way for throwing someone or something out of a window. Is there, or could we imagine, a similar word for "throwing (someone) under the bus?" Not as literal as 'sacrifice', but rather something more whimsical, in the same vein as defenestrate?

Comment: I guess *steamrolling* is too worn-out to be whimsical any more, but when people first came up with it it must have been almost exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @HansAdler Good word, but it implies that the actor is driving the bus, rather than throwing someone under it.

Comment: On reflection, *to steamroller* would have been a bit closer as it's more suggestive of the derived meaning "causing someone to be crushed by a steamroller". Probably still little use, though.

Comment: Sure: **They threw him under the bus**.

Comment: To _subject_ is, in a literal sense, to "throw under".

Comment: I misunderstood this question when I first read it (before the description) and was hoping to find a specific word for throwing someone out of a bus window!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could generally ***subvehiculate*** someone, maybe? (*Subvehiculation* would be the obvious noun then).

In reference to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230285/pronunciation-of-bifurcate-as-an-adjective/230292), you could even say the person that was handled in such a way was *subvehiculate*, as an adjective; of course with a schwa in the final syllable).

Comment: I think the "obvious" noun would be *subvehiculation*, not *subvehiculisation* since your verb is not *subvehiculise* :)

Comment: I really like subvehiculate, it has that faux-erudition quality of defenestrate. It could only be improved by finding a 'vehicle' word that is specific to a bus.

Comment: Given that the Latin word for bus is *laophorium* (from modern Greek), finding a more bus-y base word that actually works could be tricky.

Comment: Since it's only a joke anyway, you could use "omnibus". It's not Latin for "bus", but it is the word from which "bus" derives in English, so one can imagine that "subomnibise" or something came along with it :-)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան: Sometimes the obvious is not _that_ obvious :) Your suggestion, on second thought, seems more obvious though (if that ain't a contradiction in terms.)

Comment: I'm accepting *subvehiculate*, wishing I could also accept @ScotM's answer because it's a fabulous construction (though it should be subusticate, eh?). But this is a better word. It's mellifluous and it doesn't need deep analysis to figure it out when you first see it.

Answer (score 11):

Since nothing in the dictionary quite fits, we can cut and paste to build

***[Subusticate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neologism):***

> VERB
>
> to sacrifice an innocent subordinate to the the crushing
> condemnation and wrath of the larger community for the sake of
> maintaining the boss's pristine self-asserted innocence:

---

The explicit word picture of the root *bus* hides behind the *t* , a dental accommodation for the generic [*-ic*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ic&searchmode=none) suffix:

> adjective suffix, "having to do with, having the nature of, being,
> made of, caused by, similar to" (in chemistry, indicating a higher
> valence than names in -ous),
>
> from French -ique and directly from Latin -icus, which in many cases
> represents Greek -ikos "in the manner of; pertaining to."
>
> From PIE *-(i)ko, which also yielded Slavic -isku, adjectival suffix
> indicating origin, the source of the -sky (Russian -skii) in many
> surnames.

***Bustic***: having to do with **both** the *bus* and getting *busted*, because the boss can never be busted, and you are close enough to the door to fall out without any pushing that would be obvious from outside the bus.

*A **bustic** atmosphere filled the boardroom when the scandal was revealed.*

---

The prefix [*sub*-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sub-) is slightly obfuscated by the assimilation of the final *b*:

> word-forming element meaning "under, beneath; behind; from under;
> resulting from further division,"
>
> from Latin preposition sub "under,
> below, beneath, at the foot of," also "close to, up to, towards;" of
> time, "within, during;" figuratively "subject to, in the power of;"
> also "a little, somewhat" (as in sub-horridus "somewhat rough").
>
> This is said to be from PIE *(s)up- (perhaps representing *ex-upo-), a
> variant form of the root *upo- "from below," hence "turning upward,
> upward, up, up from under, over, beyond" (cognates: Sanskrit upa
> "near, under, up to, on," Greek hypo "under," Gothic iup, Old Norse,
> Old English upp "up, upward," Hittite up-zi "rises"). The Latin word
> also was used as a prefix and in various combinations.
>
> In Latin assimilated to following -c-, -f-, -g-, -p-, and often -r-
> and -m-. In Old French the prefix appears in the full Latin form only
> "in learned adoptions of old Latin compounds" [OED], and in popular
> use it was represented by sous-, sou-; as in French souvenir from
> Latin subvenire, souscrire (Old French souzescrire) from subscribere,
> etc.
>
> The original meaning is now obscured in many words from Latin
> (suggest, suspect, subject, etc.). The prefix is active in Modern
> English, sometimes meaning "subordinate" (as in subcontractor);
> "inferior" (17c., as in subhuman); "smaller" (18c.); "a part or
> division of" (c.1800, as in subcontinent).

***Subustic***: Pertaining throwing you *under* our *bus* when we *bust* you, because you are ***under*** us, and nobody *under* you is big enough for spectators to consider a worthy sacrifice.

*John felt his chest restrict with **subustic** dread.*

---

All our actions will remain obscured by plausible deniability, but something has to happen, hence the suffix [*-ate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ate#-ate-3):

> SUFFIX
>
> Forming verbs such as defenestrate, *subusticate*.
>
> *Never doubt they will **subusticate** someone before culpability can reach the top.*

---

Other derivatives:

*Subusticate* (n): the quasi-willing sacrifice: *Who saw the logic of assigning Judy as **subusticate** for Sam's crime?*

*Subusticant* (n): the loyal employee announcing the verdict publicly: *Top brass appointed Harry as **subusticant** for the press conference.*

*Subusticade* (n): the crowd of loyal employees surrounding the subusticant to help throw the victim gracefully under the bus: *Ted's **subusticade** was so big we assumed they were covering up for the President himself.*

*Subustication* (n):  the act of throwing another loyal employee under the bus: ***Subustication** was suddenly the third most common cause of termination at Greyhound.*

Comment: Marvelous answer, bravo. Now we just need to get it into general use!

Comment: Just so that no one thinks this authoritative and proof that _surbusticate_ is a generally accepted word, you should probably specify that you’re making up a neologism here.

Comment: Well thought out and well written [balderdash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balderdash), if I have even seen it. +1.

Comment: I'd prefer _subusticate_ or _debusticate_

Comment: as `defenestrate` describes an object *reference* a window, this word must also describe an object *reference* a bus.  i'm fine with your root **bus**; however we need to use the prefix `sub-` rather than `sur-` to accomplish the same.  `surbusticate` suggests above or on top of the bus.

Comment: By popular demand, the "etymology" and spelling has been changed for *subusticate*. English belongs to *Everyman*.

Answer (score 5):

The French word *dérouler* means to unroll or *to make flat*. That certainly can happen to someone that ends up under a bus. So, maybe **derolate**

Thinking of falling under a chariot's wheels (carrum in Latin, giving us *car*, *cart* and *carriage*) might suggest something simple like **decarate**, which is not very decorous, but is quite *decarrous*, and you may want to avert your eyes.

Comment: How does _de-_ fit in with _under_, _hit by_, in case of the wheel? Wouldn't a different prefix be more suitable? In _defenestrate_, _de-_ implies the outward action of being removed through the window, but in this case, the movement is towards the actual source of eventual pain. I'd rather suggest _subcarrate_ or _encarrate_.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but since is whimsical anyway, I stuck with the *de-* prefix only out of personal preference for the sound or the words.

Comment: + 1 for obfuscatory effect combined with real meaning!

Comment: Latin *plaustrum* ("wagon") might suit better than the word for chariot.

Comment: *succarate* would do the trick rather than *decarate*.

Answer (score 2):

As the origin of the modern bus is [indisputably French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus#Early_history), I suggest using the original French word to convey the root meaning:

> *[voiture](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/voiture)* - a carriage, wagon, or other wheeled vehicle.
>
> *[(voiture) omnibus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus#Etymology)* - (carriage) for all

I do not think the goal should be to necessarily make the term's definition immediately apparent (as *defenestrate* is not).

The prefix is just as important as the root, lest we confuse our readers or listeners.  Since the root is French, we can use the prefix `sub-`:

> ***sub**voiture* correctly identifies our object as below or under the bus.

Now, for a little action:

> ***subvoiturate*** - to be/put under the bus

Comment: Problem: in current day-to-day French *voiture* just means "car" (in the broad "multi-person private vehicle" sense of *car* in English), making those in the know read *subvoiturate* as meaning "throw under the... car?" This is unlike *defenestrate*, which those in the know can read and understand directly. I like this approach, but "voiture" just doesn't carry the weight being asked of it here.

Comment: modern french, yes, but also of a *vehicle* in general, so i think the meaning is there.  users of `defenestrate` rarely question what type of window the object exited.

Comment: It's a stretch, since *voiture* excludes buses. This is unlike *fenestre*, which does not include some windows but not others. Since this is specifically for **buses**, a morpheme that excludes buses isn't ideal. I do like the approach though. Speaking French myself though, *subvoiturate* looks silly (in the wrong way).

Comment: i agree it's silly.  can't help that definitions change over time.  in one sense, *subvoiturate* has that archaic feel to it, something that *bus* (a near universal word) does not.  (like balderdashing a word based around "stop".)  personally, i like *subvehiculate*.

Comment: The trouble is, "voiture omnibus" hasn't been used to mean English *bus* since the 19th century, and then only for a brief period of time measured in months. It's an interesting etymological footnote, but *voiture* is the wrong half of the etymological origin of *bus* — our word came from latin *omnibus*, as illogical as that is at the semantic level.